# $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R, f(x) = \frac{1}{e^x+e^{-x}}$ and $I_n=\int_n^{n+1}f(x)dx$. Show $f(n+1) \le I_n \le f(n)$

Tags: calculus, inequality, definite-integrals

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{e^x+e^{-x}}$$
$$I_n=\int_n^{n+1}f(x)dx\,\,\,\,\, n\in\mathbb N^*$$
Show $f(n+1) \le I_n \le f(n)$.
I don't know what to do here. I realized that $I_n$ can be calculated and also that $f(x)$ is decreasing but I still don't see the relation.
$\int{f(x)dx}=\arctan e^x => I_n=\arctan e^{n+1}-\arctan e^n$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your function is decreasing on $[0,\infty)$. Therefore, for each $x\in[n,n+1]$, $f(x)\leqslant f(n)$ and so$$I_n=\int_n^{n+1}f(x)\,\mathrm dx\leqslant\int_n^{n+1}f(n)\,\mathrm dx=f(n).$$The other inequality is similar.

Answer (score 0):

using the inequality $m(b-a)\leq \int_a^b f(x)dx\leq M.(b-a)$, here $a=n,b=n+1$ , and the function is decreasing, hence $m=f(n+1),M=f(n)$ .

Here  $m,M$ as usual gobal minimum and maximum of $f$ on $[a,b]$ respectievly.